# how to execute telnet login using perl?

Tags: windows, expect

When I execute the script given below in Unix, it works fine.

```
        #!/usr/bin/expect -f 
        spawn telnet 10.123.9.111 
        expect login {send username\r} 
        expect password {send password\r} 
        interact;
```

When I execute the same script on Windows, it shows as can't execute /usr/bin/expect at example.pl I have installed `expect` from `perl package manager.`

Is there any way to add it's equivalent dynamic link library on Windows?

Or, how can I telnet login using perl script on Windows?

Comment: That script isn't perl, it's expect, which is a completely different language and a completely different project. The Expect.pm that you installed from PPM is *not* the same thing. There are instructions in getting expect for windows at http://expect.sourceforge.net/ — one of the options is ActiveState ActiveTcl (note: *not* ActivePerl).

Comment: how to make it possible usin perl script ? is it possible ?

Comment: Expect `!=` Perl. They are **two different languages**.

Comment: how to execute expect script on windows ? how different it's from unix ?

Comment: 0_o Unix and Windows are **operating systems**. Expect is a **programming language**. A simple Google search reveals that there seem to be implementations of Expect that are built for Windows.

Comment: @ Jack : Can you please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931250/how-to-install-expect-for-windows-64-bit ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl (not expect) to telnet from Windows can be done with Net::Telnet.

Comment: I tried that too but i couldn't eliminate this error : pattern match timed-out at filename.pl (Indicates for password line).

use Net::Telnet;
$telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>10,
Errmode=>'die');
$telnet->open('10.100.1.111');
$telnet->waitfor('/login: $/i');
$telnet->print('xbcnfhkrj');
$telnet->waitfor('/password: $/i');
$telnet->print('dfdghrhrktit');

Answer (score 0):

The #!/usr/bin/expect -f won't work on windows.

You'll have to give a windows like path to tell where expect is.

Something like (really depends on your path in windows),

```
"C:\strawberry\perl/bin/expect"
```

Or just #!perl if perl is in your environment path.

Comment: @ Ahmed : Thank u. But i tried with it("C:\Perl64/site/lib/Bundle) earlier bt again same error.